# Regra PREG MATCH apropriada

Tags: php, array, regex, preg-match

Criei um loop que mostra todos os mêses do ano com o código seguinte:

```
for($i = 1;$i <= 12;$i++){

}
```

então criei uma variável $_GET que receberia uma regra como a seguinte: 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
 
Esta é a variável $_GET:

```
$listaMesesPagos = isset($_GET["mesespg"]) ? $_GET["mesespg"] : null;$listaMesesPagos = is_string($listaMesesPagos) ? $listaMesesPagos : null;
```

O objetivo dessa variável $_GET é mostrar os meses que foram pagos pela pessoa X. Por exemplo se a pessoa X pagou a sua mensalidade nos mêses: **Janeiro, Fevereiro e Março** (1,2,3). Então a $_GET receberia os valores: 1,2 e 3 na seguinte maneira: **http://localhost/pagina.php?mesespg=1,2,3** que mais tarde seria jogada em uma **ARRAY** php através do **explode()** ficando assim:

```
$arrayMeses = explode(",",$listaMesesPagos);
```

Mas para usar o **explode()** é necessário primeiro saber se a variável $_GET recebeu na seguinte regra: **n,n,n** que neste exemplo é: **1,2,3** por isso usei a preg_match com o $pattern a seguir:

```
$regraDaListaDosMeses = '/^([0-9]{1,2}\,{1}){1,11}([0-9]){0,1}$/';
```

Dessa forma, antes de usar o explode o php verifica se a variável $_GET está nesta regra acima: (1,2,3). Caso esteja o PHP jogará os números para uma array parecida com esta: array(1,2,3); caso contrário o php criará uma array vazia para evitar erros como está no código a seguir:

```
if(preg_match($regraDaListaDosMeses, $listaMesesPagos) == true){
$arrayMeses = explode(",",$listaMesesPagos);
}else{
    $arrayMeses = array();
}
```

Então o loop **for()** checaria se os mes atual está na array **$arrayMeses** caso não mostraria que o mês está pendente. Segue o código:

```
            for($i = 1;$i <= 12;$i++){
            /*mês pago*/if(in_array($i, $arrayMeses)){/*CÓDIGO AQUI*/}
            /*mês não pago*/else{/*CÓDIGO AQUI*/}
        }
```

Agora, com base nessa "**delicada**" explicação. :) vamos ao problema que está na regra do preg_match.
vejam, na regra: **/^([0-9]{1,2}\,{1}){1,11}([0-9]){0,1}$/**. Esta não está apropriada. Eu quero uma regra que verifica que, por exemplo, os seguintes carácteres estão corretos: **1,2,3**;**1,2,3,**;**1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12**.

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um [número](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) inteiro [entre](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.alternation.php) 1 e 12:

```
[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

[Agrupado](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

```
(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

Seguido por uma vírgula ou o fim do texto ([`$`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.meta.php)):

```
(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:,|$)
```

[Repetir](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.repetition.php) 0 a 12 vezes:

```
(?:(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:,|$)){0,12}
```

Desde o início ([`^`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.meta.php)) até o final do texto ([`$`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.meta.php)):

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:,|$)){0,12}$
```

Então:

```
$regraDaListaDosMeses = '/^(?:(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:,|$)){0,12}$/';
```

[Demo no regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/czy55k/1)

---

**Alternativamente**, você pode filtrar apenas meses válidos do array usando [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$listaMesesPagos = '1,@@@,4,,7,128,9,ooo10,11,';
$arrayMeses = explode( ',', $listaMesesPagos);

$regraMes = '/^(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])$/';

$arrayMeses = preg_grep( $regraMes, $arrayMeses);
```

```
var_export($arrayMeses);
```

Resultado:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  2 => '4',
  4 => '7',
  6 => '9',
  8 => '11',
)
```

Ou sem expressões regulares, usando [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php).